# Trying to install Xfce on Ubuntu Server 18.04 but no GUI on reboot

Tags: server, xfce, gui

When I run

```
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get upgrade 
Sudo apt-get install xfce4
```

On Ubuntu server 18.04, it says it installed all the packages but when i reboot i still don't have a GUI! What am i doing wrong???

The other post is using

```
sudo apt install --no-install-recommends xubuntu-core
```

I'm very unclear why

```
sudo apt-get install xfce4
```

Is not giving me a GUI. I don't want my server to be turned into a full-blown desktop (I don't want a bunch of software and applications that I don't need ) GUI I just want the base of Xfce. Unless I'm missing something here and

```
sudo apt install --no-install-recommends xubuntu-core
```

is just the base, either way please explain, why I install xfce4 but still don't see a GUI? Is there something else that I need to install prior to this?

[Here is another example](https://www.server-world.info/en/note?os=Ubuntu_18.04&p=desktop&f=5) when I tried this method I still got no GUI.

Also in the page that you say is duplicate in the third post down the answer is to run

```
sudo apt-get install xfce4
```

to install Xfce desktop and that doesn't work for me.

Comment: Did you set what is your default init run time ?

Comment: ?? Dunno what your talking about ! Init run time ???

Comment: Have you tried to run `startx`? To have it started automatically, I suppose you should install [`xubuntu-core`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=xubuntu-core).

Comment: You have installed something, but that does not mean that it automatically starts!  See here: https://wiki.xfce.org/faq  Try the command `startxfce4`

Comment: there it is the startxfce4 worked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not doing anything wrong, just not quite done yet.

Install a ["Display Manager"](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/display_manager).

In short the display manager is the GUI login screen that will load the requested "Window Manager", like XFCE, with the entered user credentials.

Comment: thats what i was doing wrong i was under the understanding that the display manager was part of the desktop enviroment thanks so much.

Comment: Really glad it helped. What display manager did you end up using?

Comment: I recommend to [edit] this answer to expand it with specific details about how to do this. (See also [How do I write a good answer?](/help/how-to-answer) for general advice about what sorts of answers are considered most valuable on Ask Ubuntu.)

Comment: @DavidFoerster you're welcome to complete the answer by editing or making new one

Comment: @APu So are you. :-] (Do you see the problem now?)